# Test for treatment change

Tags: hypothesis-testing, agreement-statistics

I have a study where the goal is to see if a new diagnostic tool provides any addition to the old procedure. A set of patients have been diagnosed and classified into 7 categories, each corresponding to a given treatment. The new diagnostic tool is then used, and the patients are diagnosed and classified again. Patients are then classified into two categories:

1. the suggested treatment remains the same; or
2. the suggested treatment is changed.

It seems as if this should be a simple question, but still I can't figure out what kind of test I could use to see if the diagnostic tool provides any additional information leading to revision of treatment. Given that there is a test, I would also like to do some sample size calculations for the next part of the study.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing which classification is correct (a so-called 'gold standard')? Are you wanting to know if the new tool is an *improvement*, or only if the 2 procedures *agree*?

Comment: Only agreement is considered, it is not possible to tell which procedure is the better.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the two different diagnostic tools as different 'raters', and assess the *interrater agreement*. The prototypical analysis is [Cohen's kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).  Jon Uebersax has a [webpage](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/agree.htm) dedicated to interrater agreement with lots of good information; you'll probably want to spend some time there learning more about it.

If you use R, there is the [irr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/index.html) for assessing interrater agreement.  It has functions for calculating Cohen's kappa ([?kappa2](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/irr/html/kappa2.html)), and for calculating power / sample size ([?N2.cohens.kappa](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/r_function?p=irr&f=N2.cohen.kappa)).